# DevC++ (Mingw) Stack Limit

Tags: c++, windows, dev-c++

Is it possible to set the stack limit in DevC++? Basically the same as "ulimit -s" would do on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving this option to `ld` (the linker):

> `--stack` *reserve*
>   `--stack` *reserve,commit*
>      Specify the number of bytes of memory to reserve (and optionally commit) to be used as stack for this program. The default is 2Mb reserved, 4K committed. [This option is specific to the i386 PE targeted port of the linker]

http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options